# Grouping a List using an unequal key extractor and classifier function

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to group elements in a list of commits (class `LegacyCommit`) such that all commits to the same user belong in its own map.

Here is the code to first obtain the `nonDistinctCommits`

```
Map<Boolean, List<LegacyCommit>> partitionedCommits = pushEvent.getCommits().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(LegacyCommit::isDistinct));

List<LegacyCommit> distinctCommits = partitionedCommits.get(true);
List<LegacyCommit> nonDistinctCommits = partitionedCommits.get(false);
```

Now I want to obtain a `Map<LegacyUser, List<LegacyCommit>>` by grouping on `commit -> commit.getCommitter().getUsername()`, however I get into two situations that neither work:

**Situation 1**

```
Map<LegacyUser, List<LegacyCommit>> committerGroupedNonDistinctCommits = nonDistinctCommits.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LegacyCommit::getCommitter));
```

This comes close, but maps on `LegacyCommiter::getCommitter`, which does not have an `equals()` method defined nor do I want to do it via this way.

So instead I use end up in...

**Situation 2**

I want to group on the username, while storing the `LegacyUser` in the map as key, I attempted this:

```
Map<LegacyUser, List<LegacyCommit>> committerGroupedNonDistinctCommits = nonDistinctCommits.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(commit -> commit.getCommitter().getUsername(), Collectors.mapping(LegacyCommit::getCommitter, Collectors.toList())));
```

But it cannot compile as the type arguments are wrong.

So the question is as follows:

How can I obtain a `Map<LegacyUser, List<LegacyCommit>>` from a `List<LegacyCommit>` grouping on `commit -> commit.getComitter().getUsername()`?

Comment: Just to throw in extra confusion... Committer and Author are not always the same person!!

Answer (score 3):

I assume that *username* is a `String` (though any `Comparable` will do with this solution). Then you can group by *committer* into a sorted `Map` which is sorted by the *username* of the *committer*:

```
Map<LegacyUser, List<LegacyCommit>> committerGroupedNonDistinctCommits =
    nonDistinctCommits.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        LegacyCommit::getCommitter,
        ()->new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(LegacyUser::getUserName)),
        Collectors.toList()));
```

A sorted map will treat keys as equal which are equal according to the `Comparator` and the *group by* `Collector` will use the mapping of the supplied `Map`. So it doesn’t matter when `LegacyUser` has no `equals` method.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to use a three-step solution.

1. Collect a `Map<String, List<LegacyCommit>> commitsByUsername`
2. Create an empty `Map<LegacyUser, List<LegacyCommit>> results`
3. Loop through the Lists in `commitsByUsername` and for each item, get the first commit from the list, use that as a key and add the list itself to `results`

I tried many different approaches using a bunch of streams and collectors at first but always ended up with a compiler error. It feels like sometimes the simplest solutions are the best ones.

I do not believe that you at the moment will be able to do this using a typical Java 8 one-liner.

Here is a SSCCE:

```
static class User {
    private static int COUNTER = 0;
    String username;
    int notSame = COUNTER++;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%s: %d}", username, notSame);
    }

}
static class LegacyCommit {
    User user;
    String value;

    public static LegacyCommit create(String user, String value) {
        LegacyCommit commit = new LegacyCommit();
        commit.user = new User();
        commit.user.username = user;
        commit.value = value;
        return commit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s by %s", value, user);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<LegacyCommit> commits = new ArrayList<>();
    commits.add(LegacyCommit.create("a", "v1"));
    commits.add(LegacyCommit.create("b", "v2"));
    commits.add(LegacyCommit.create("c", "v3"));
    commits.add(LegacyCommit.create("a", "v4"));
    commits.add(LegacyCommit.create("b", "v5"));
    commits.add(LegacyCommit.create("c", "v6"));
    commits.add(LegacyCommit.create("a", "v7"));


    Map<String, List<LegacyCommit>> commitsByUsername = commits.stream().collect(groupingBy(commit -> commit.user.username));
    Map<User, List<LegacyCommit>> resultsss = new HashMap<>();
    commitsByUsername.values().forEach(list -> resultsss.put(list.get(0).user, list));
    System.out.println(resultsss);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.  First group by username then remake the map using `getCommiter()` as key.

```
Map<LegacyUser, List<LegacyCommit>> committerGroupedNonDistinctCommits = 
    nonDistinctCommits.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(c -> c.getCommiter().getUsername()))
        .values().stream()
        .collect(toMap(lst -> lst.get(0).getCommiter(), lst->lst));
```